# ExtJS and Ajax with SSL (https)

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have an ExtJS application on top of a Django application, and I need to post to `/accounts/logout/` in order to invalidate the session and then redirect to `/`.

The code below runs locally but fails on the live site, which has SSL. I have an issue with doing the Ajax POST via ExtJS. The code is the following:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/accounts/logout/',
    withCredentials: true,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        console.log('successfully logged out');
        window.location.href='/'
    }
});
```

The response status in Chrome is `(cancelled)` as shown in this screenshot:
[image]

In addition I get this warning at console level:

> The page at `https://domain.example.com/` displayed insecure content
>   from `http://console.pharmacy.com.mt/`.

Am I missing some config object with the `Ext.Ajax` request above?

Comment: Is the request going from `http` to `https`? If so, that would make it a cross domain request.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The single-page app is rendered and served over `https`;  in my case any `http` request is redirected to its `https` version via the Nginx web server. So it should be from `https` to `https`.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that should't work. Out of interest, what if you wrap the `window.location` call in a `setTimeout`, say, 10ms?

Comment: try removing `withCredentials: true,` see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> try removing withCredentials: true

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/accounts/logout/',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        console.log('successfully logged out');
        window.location.href='/'
    }
});
```